# No Numbers on busybox menuconfig search results

Tags: configuration, busybox, yocto

Sorry if this naive question, but while using the `kconfig` system for the kernel and buildroot, when I hit <kbd>/</kbd> for search, the results always have shortcut numbers on the left to navigate to them quickly.

Currently, I am using Yocto, and when I enter the busybox menuconfig by issuing `bitbake -c menuconfig busybox` I don't see those numbers, I there any option to make them show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Busybox’s version of Kconfig is very old: it was copied from the kernel in 2006, and subsequent changes to the kernel’s Kconfig haven’t been imported. Support for jump keys in search results [was added to the kernel in 2012](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5e609addb1bd963ce1a1929f2012c8dd04ca8620).

Busybox’s Kconfig doesn’t support jump keys in search results, and there’s no configuration option to make them show up.